# how can i specify in my migration not to migrate unpublished content?

Tags: migrations

in a drupal 8 migration, is there a way to specify in the .yml that i dont want to migrate any content that is unpublished .  Or would that have to be done in a plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the [skip on value](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/2902867) plugin.

Untested, but probably like:

```
process:
  status:
    plugin: skip_on_value
    method: row
    not_equals: true
    value: 1
    source: status
```

Should only import published content.